# Unable to expose port using EXPOSE in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to expose a JMX port to monitor SpringBoot Application from minikube.
So I added EXPOSE 9010 in Dockerfile and following in deployment.yaml

```yaml
- containerPort: 9010
- name: JAVA_OPTS  
              value: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 \
                      -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010 \
                      -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
```

however, the port is not getting exposed. Am I missing something here?
Getting below error when trying to port-forward

```
Handling connection for 9010
E0223 11:48:52.999502   17966 portforward.go:400] an error occurred forwarding 9010 -> 9010: error forwarding port 9010 to pod 4dc803f4d28b82b98dbc0e8fc1448d760f98694e026fb74511b2b8957aa88ef3, uid : exit status 1: 2021/02/23 06:18:52 socat[16604] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:9010, 16): Connection refused
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /
ADD target/usgagg-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar //
EXPOSE 9010
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dspring.profiles.active=local","-jar","usgagg-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Note: Springboot server.port is 8080 and I dint create any service to expose 8080 port, I've just added container port in deployment.yaml and it's working fine. I've problem with 9010 only

Update:
Issue is resolved by modifying ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile to below.

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar /usgagg-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Expose is just documentation, it doesn't actually do anything. You have to find some way of exposing that port in kubernetes, through say a nodeport.

Comment: It seems that JMX is not running. You need to start it. It could also be that you have a firewall blocking traffic on that port

Comment: I've created below service for nodeport. Still it's the same error.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: usgagg-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: usgagg-service
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9010
    targetPort: 9010

Comment: @Oussama, Could you please let me know how do I start JMX?

Comment: Can you share other key elements of your docket file in the question like the base, the entry point etc.

Comment: Great you have solved it. You can add the answer below so that it is clear for future readers.